# Creating array in controller and passing to external function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to take existing/working code from a laravel controller and create an array of customers from an existing query function in that controller.

Here is the controller code portion that works:

CONTROLLER

```
$d->createdAt = new \DateTime($d->created_at);
$deadline = Carbon::now()->subMonths(2);
if($d->nextDate <= $now && $d->createdAt > $deadline && $d->status != 'exempt'){
    $d->status = 'priority';
}
```

That block of code works by taking an existing query in the controller, querying the 'created_at' column in the database, and if it's within the last 6 months it applys a status of 'priority' which is used as a css class to highlight.

That works perfectly.

Now, I want to take any affected customer from that query ($d->custNum) with a status of 'priority', put it in an array and then pass the array to my function called findActive in my activeCust.php file

activeCust.php

```
public function findActive($custNum){

    $sql ="
        SELECT c.customer
          FROM customers C
        WHERE c.customer NOT IN ($custNum)
    ";
}
```

Basically, after that code block in the controller, I want to create an array of all returned customer numbers (i.e. the status of 'priority') and pass that array to the function so that I can say "Run this findActive query on any customer that isn't in this array".

The idea here is extending the working code into a new file that does the same highlighting but works off of different logic. I'm just not sure the best way to create the array so that I can pass it into the function properly.

How can I create an array from the returned values in the controller code block and use the array for my 'NOT IN' in the function query in activeCust.php?

Comment: Whats your question, please explain clearly and short

Comment: I feel like it's explained pretty clearly, but look at my final sentence. My controller code works properly and my function query works in general. I just want to create an array from the results of the controller code block and pass it to the function query

Comment: where do you call the `findActive()` function in the first place?

Comment: where is function call and that array.?

Comment: I'm not calling the function yet, I'm still building that function in an external file but it's included in the controller.

Comment: Basically I want to say (IF $d->status = 'newCust', create array newCust[]) or something similar. And then in my function query I want to use $newCust[] to say run query on anything not in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your question is not clear, there's an assumption I have. If it is not correct, I'll delete the answer so you can restructure your question:

- In that logic, i.e `if` statement, you want to populate an array that would keep the ids of the `$d` record (better if you give it more explanatory variable name):

If my assumption is correct, you can initialize an array, then populate it with other ids in the condition block as this:

```
$ids = [];

if($d->nextDate <= $now && $d->createdAt > $deadline && $d->status != 'exempt'){
    $d->status = 'priority';
    $ids[] = $d->custNum
}
....
SomeClass::findActive($ids); //calls the findActive()
```

> An observation is why you are using Query String when you can use Eloquent or even QueryBuilders' `whereNotIn('something', [1,2,3]);` for example?

Comment: Apologies for any confusion, but yes that looks spot on! In this case, could I keep the query in the function as it is though? Or I guess I would have to make it use $ids

Comment: The signature, that is, the name you use as argument in the `findActive()` declaration doesn't matter I used `$ids` as example. But I see in your case, its just need to be an array or comma separated string?. But if you'll use it with the raw query string you'll need to use `implode(',', $ids)` to make it a string.

Comment: Ah I see. I'll use it as is, but in my function I'll make $custNum = implode(',',$ids);

Comment: If that suits you, but since you use Laravel I will strongly recommend you take advantage of Eloquent or Query Builders: see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries